# HTML - Images wont display

Tags: html, image

I am new to HTML and I am struggling with understanding why my code is failing.  I am trying to insert an image and the image is just showing up as a blue box with a question mark in it. the code is as follows:

```
<head>

<title>Welcome</title>
</head>

<h1> heading here</h1>

<p> insert webpage below </p>

<a href=“http://www.imdb.com/”>IMDB</a>

<p> why dont you email me </p>

<a href=“mailto:cheethamemma5@gmail.com”>Email Emma</a>

<img src= “Users/Emma/Documents/code/images/bird.jpeg” alt=ERROR

</body>
```

Comment: your img tag isnt closed

Comment: Well, first I would fix your `<img>` tag by properly closing it like this: `<img src= “Users/Emma/Documents/code/images/bird.jpeg” alt=ERROR />`. But your main problem is that the path is probably incorrect. It needs to be a retaliative path to that of the HTML file

Comment: To add to the above - the `"` seem odd. Make sure these are regular double quotes.

Comment: Thank - you! I had smart quotes on which I have now corrected. I have closed the tag and put error in brackets.

Comment: However, I can only think the source is wrong  - I put the absolute pathway hoping it would work. I have moved the image into the code file. The HTML file is also in the code file. Pathway for image is: Users/Emma/Documents/code/bird.jpeg. Pathway for code is: Users/Emma/Documents/code/index.html

Comment: it worked - Thankyou!! very happy!

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 things w.r.t. question.

You are not closing your `img` properly. Update your `img` tag from

```
<img src= “Users/Emma/Documents/code/images/bird.jpeg” alt=ERROR
```

to

```
<img src= “Users/Emma/Documents/code/images/bird.jpeg” alt="ERROR"/>
```

**Other important point** - Make sure your image is available at location relative to your html i.e. in parallel to your html there must be a folder Users and in that folder Emma folder and so on till bird.jpeg.

Comment: Ya.... `Users/Emma/Documents/...` looks like a absolute path to the image on your local machine.

Comment: also put ERROR in quotes